# How to draw the line maximum Height for Highchart(area spline)

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

How can I draw the line for each week maximum height?

Here is my js code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'CPM, IMPS, SPEND, etc'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Week 1',
            'Week 2',
            'Week 3',
            'Week 4',
            'Week 5',
            'Week 6',
            'Week 7',
            'Week 8']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'No title required'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' units'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'CPM',
        data: [6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
    }, {
        name: 'IMPS',
        data: [1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
    }]

}, function (chart) { // on complete
    chart.renderer.rect(117, 195, 3, 168, 0).attr({fill: 'red', zIndex:3}).add();

});
});
```

And here is a fiddle of my problem:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbDRG/1/)

Thank you In Advance

Comment: Do you just need it to be a grid? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/dbDRG/7/

Comment: How to customize the cross Hair with start and end point for each series.Example start with 50 and end with 250 for the Y axis Position.

Comment: Can you please post an image indicating and explaining where do you want the lines to appear ?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/gm74d/)**
You will have to add a `plotLine` on `x-axis` like:

```
plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 3,
                value: 0.2
            }]
```

Refer `xAxis.plotLines` [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines)

Here is the complete code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CPM, IMPS, SPEND, etc'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 150,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Week 1',
                'Week 2',
                'Week 3',
                'Week 4',
                'Week 5',
                'Week 6',
                'Week 7',
                'Week 8'],
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 3,
                value: 0.2
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'No title required'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'CPM',
            data: [6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
        }, {
            name: 'IMPS',
            data: [1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: No . this case should first Plot line should be 6[In Y axis] and second plot Line should be 3[In Y axis]

Comment: Please explain briefly on which axis and at what values do you want `plotLines` to appear ?

Comment: For Your reference http://jsfiddle.net/gm74d/3/ open my jsfiddle. I am trying prepare a line between my maximum Yaxis value to My x-Axis[category ] . See my jsfiddle. I want to draw the Line [Red colored One ie, Left hand side ]  till Week1. Here see My first series Maximum value[54] and lowest value [12] series: [{
            name: 'CPM',
            data: [54, 3, 4, 3, 5, 14, 10, 33]
        }, {
            name: 'IMPS',
            data: [12, 5, 3, 4, 3, 11, 5, 42]
        }, {
            name: 'Spend',
            data: [15, 7, 3, 14, 2, 8, 15, 19]
        }
   Thanks in advance

Comment: You draw this line, which is correct, so where the problem is?

Comment: I think @user3824730 wants something different other than this, I can't figure out what he means to say. Please refer his comment above that one of yours. May be you would be able to help him !

Comment: Hi,. I draw the Line between Y axis-start and end. but I need draw the Line till [x0,Y0] axis. I could not able to find out the position [x0,Y0] .